# How to integrate Android app with Google Voice Command

Tags: android

As a new Nexus 7 owner, I love Google Voice Action's integration with their clock app to create alarms, as I use it all the time to "Remind me to take out the trash at 8:00 pm" (for example). However, one thing it doesn't do that I wish it did was provide a widget that shows a list of all of your active alarms, including the description and time/date.

To that end, I'd like to create my own alarm app that does just that. I'm a pretty experienced Android developer but I am completely unfamiliar with the Google Voice Action APIs, so I'm not really sure where to begin. Searches on the subject brought me to the Android Developer blog with an entry on its use with music apps, but nothing in the area I'm looking into.

There's two subjects of the API I need to know - how to register my app with Voice Actions to handle "Remind me to" actions (so it pops up alongside any other to-do apps when receiving the command), and how to parse the actual voice command from Voice Actions into the app (so in the above example, it will pass "take out the trash" and "8:00 pm" as values back to the app). Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where to get started?

Thank you!